# How to collapse a matrix in R while getting min and max of some columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R. It represents a made up protein structure for ease of explanation.

```
Uniprots Chain resSeq Serial
P68871  D   23  3446
P68871  D   24  3453
P68871  D   25  3457
P68871  D   26  3461
P68871  D   27  3470
P69011  A   38  3561
P69011  A   39  3568
P69011  A   40  3577
P69011  A   41  3588
P69011  A   42  3599
P69011  A   43  3610
P69011  A   44  3619
P69011  A   45  3625
P69011  A   46  3636
P0116   B   2   4239
P0116   B   4   4242
P0116   B   5   4268
P0116   B   6   4279
P0116   B   7   4285
P0116   B   8   4299
P0116   B   9   5015
P0116   C   15  5055
P0116   C   30  5199
P0116   C   42  5239
```

What I want is to collapse it down so it looks like this:

```
Uniprot Chain resSeq_start resSeq_end Serial_start Serial_end
P68871   D      23            27          3446       3470
P69011   A      38            46          3561       3636
P0116    B       2             9          4239       5015
P0116    C      15            42          5055       5239
```

Basically, I want to collapse down over the first 1,2 and 3 columns. I can then use the the 4th column as a check that it worked. I thought I could do this with aggregate but that doesn't seem to work. I can definitely do this with some messy for loops (keep appending to a vector till a new uniprot/chain) but that's ugly.

One thing to note is that Uniprot/Chain combinations are not always unique. Specifically, a uniprot can have multiple chains (as in my example).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: should it be min(x$resSeq) or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aggregate`: a base solution (which I would prefer) provided by @user20650 (`do.call` is important since aggregate will return a data frame but with matrix elements)

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(cbind(resSeq, Serial) ~ Uniprots + Chain, 
                              data = dat, function(x) c(start = min(x), end = max(x))))

#   Uniprots Chain resSeq.start resSeq.end Serial.start Serial.end
# 1   P69011     A           38         46         3561       3636
# 2    P0116     B            2          9         4239       5015
# 3    P0116     C           15         42         5055       5239
# 4   P68871     D           23         27         3446       3470
```

`plyr`

```
dat <- psych::read.clipboard()

library(plyr)

ddply(dat, .(Uniprots, Chain), summarise, 
      resSeq_start = min(resSeq),
      resSeq_end = max(resSeq),
      Serial_start = Serial[which.min(resSeq)],
      Serial_end = Serial[which.max(resSeq)])

#   Uniprots Chain resSeq_start resSeq_end Serial_start Serial_end
# 1    P0116     B            2          9         4239       5015
# 2    P0116     C           15         42         5055       5239
# 3   P68871     D           23         27         3446       3470
# 4   P69011     A           38         46         3561       3636
```

(the which.min/max probably aren't needed)

Comment: what is the purpose of the do.call(data.frame...) part?

Comment: short answer: it coerces what looks like a normal data.frame (it's not) into a normal data.frame. look at the `str` with and without `do.call`.

Comment: the cbind creates a matrix on the left side of the formula, and then aggregate.formula returns a data frame. But since a data frame is just a collection of lists (which hold onto their structures), the matrix created with cbind is still there. do.call(data.frame... coerces the matrix into a data.frame so that you can use operators (`$`, `[`) or whatever on (what you expect to be a normal data.frame) without unexpected results.

Answer (score 5):

And, of course, `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Uniprots, Chain) %>%
    summarize(resSeq_start = min(resSeq),
              resSeq_end   = max(resSeq),
              Serial_start = min(Serial),
              Serial_end   = max(Serial))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend data.table.

Here is a simple implementation:

Step1: Convert data.frame to data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
```

Step2: Create new columns:

```
dt[, `:=`(resSeq_start = min(resSeq), 
          resSeq_end   = max(resSeq), 
          Serial_start = min(Serial), 
          Serial_end   = max(Serial)), 
by = list(Uniprots, Chain)]
```

Step3: Remove old columns:

```
res <- dt[, c("Serial", "resSeq") := NULL]
```

Step4: Keep only the unique columns:

```
unique(res, by=c("Uniprots", "Chain"))
#    Uniprots Chain resSeq_start resSeq_end Serial_start Serial_end
# 1:   P68871     D           23         27         3446       3470
# 2:   P69011     A           38         46         3561       3636
# 3:    P0116     B            2          9         4239       5015
# 4:    P0116     C           15         42         5055       5239
```

I've illustrated two ways to add/remove columns by reference using `data.table` here. One using `c("col", "col2") := list(val1, val2)` and the other `:=`(col1=val1, col2=val2).

Hope this helps. You should read more about data.table.

Comment: @Arun: Thanks for the edit with new feature!! Just wondering how can I stay in touch with latest developments on data.table, and possibly contribute.

Comment: Shambho, sure :). These features aren't new really. However `data.table` is evolving rapidly than ever. The best way to stay up to date is to 1) subscribe to the mailing list, 2) keep tabs on the project on [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). It'd be great if you contribute as well! To begin with, I think pull requests... Matt and/or I would be happy to help you with any questions. You can find our emails quite easily from the data.table mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Arun! Just a disclaimer that I am very new to the version control (and github). It'll require some ramping up, but am up for it. Where can I find the mailing list?

Comment: No problem :). We can help you there too. You can subscribe to the mailing list [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/mail/?group_id=240) and for old posts [go here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) and scroll to the bottom of the page to find the news feed/link of your choice.